# Drupal 7, Only logged in visitors can download

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-files

I have a Drupal 7 site that has downloadable resources (PDF files) in blocks that need to be visible to all visitors, but only available for logged in visitors to download. How can I accomplish this?

Any advice is great appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `Private files` for your file field and let Drupal handle all this.

Here is how to [work with files in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file). This should put you on the right track.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
   global $user;
   if($user->uid != "") {
           $path = "/sites/default/files/example.pdf";
   } else {
           $path ="#";
   }
   ?>
   <p><a href="<?php echo $path ?>"><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;"><span style="color: rgb(255, 153, 0);">Example.pdf</span></span></span></a></p>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not secure: whoever knows the url can download file.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This is just to hide the link. But follow as said by 
Muhammad Reda if you want to restrict the access completely.